# Create 8Bit unsigned GeoTIFF with GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to create a 8 bit GeoTIFF with this code.

Is there a way to use unsigned 8 bit? I only found the `GDT_UInt16`?

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

dataset = gdal.Open('test.tif')
driver = dataset.GetDriver()
driver.Create("out.tiff", cols, rows, 1, GDT_UInt16) # <- here

out_band = out_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
out_data = np.zeros((rows,cols), np.int16)
out_band.WriteArray(out_data, 0, 0)
out_band.FlushCache()
out_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())
out_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
```

Comment: From http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html: Currently band types of Byte, UInt16, Int16, UInt32, Int32, Float32, Float64, CInt16, CInt32, CFloat32 and CFloat64 are supported for reading and writing. Byte seems to be the closest hit.

Comment: Exactly 8 bits are 1 byte. Thank you for the reminder :)

Answer (score 5):

The gdal documentation describes the GDT_Byte as an 8 bit unsigned integer ([see here](https://naturalatlas.github.io/node-gdal/classes/Constants%20(GDT).html#prop-gdal.GDT_Byte)).
So the correct gdal constant is the `GDT_Byte`. In your code it would be:

```
driver.Create("out.tiff", cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
```

Comment: also worth noting here if you've come to this question to find how to assign this in a terminal program, you can use...

 `-ot Byte` as opposed to `-ot UInt16`